# Why doesn't validator doesn't like my jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I was just doing some validation and got some errors due to my javascript...

```
Error: document type does not allow element "strong" here

$('#myobject').html('<strong>'+multiplier+'</strong><small>&nbsp;objects</small>');
```

It seems fairly straight forward... i'm putting some html in a html function but w3c doesn't like it... Is there a doctype more suited to this?

Comment: As far as I know, w3c's validator doesn't interpret Javascript, so it must be something else (e.g., JS seen as HTML). Can you point to your page, so we can see the full source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it the actual (pre-javascript evaluation) source that is getting the validation error?

Try marking the script contents as CDATA, i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[ */
$('#myobject').html('<strong>'+multiplier+'</strong><small>&nbsp;objects</small>');
/* ]]> */
</script>
```